# Does any ongoing transgression exempt one from going to war?

Tags: army-military-war, tractate-sotah

We know from [Devarim 20:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0520.htm#8) that someone who is "fearful and faint-hearted" is sent home from battle (in optional wars) lest he demoralize others.  In [Sotah 8:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.8.5?lang=bi&with=English%20Explanation%20of%20Mishnah&lang2=en) Rabbi Yose the Galilean says this refers to transgressions he has committed (and so he's afraid of being punished, I think), and Rabbi Yose (different Yose) gives a specific list, all of which are forbidden marriages.  A commentary at Sefaria notes that these are *ongoing* transgressions (for as long as he remains married), not transgressions committed in the past.

Did *any* ongoing transgression cause one to be sent home from battle, and Rabbi Yose is just listing examples?  Or is this specifically about forbidden *marriages*, and other ongoing transgressions (like owning forbidden items) would not disqualify one?  The passage in D'varim (and in this chapter of mishna) exempts one based on a new house, a new vineyard, or a newly betrothed wife, so it might be that only ongoing transgressions involving these things are relevant.  Or it might be that a (forbidden) marriage is more *public* than those idols you have in your basement, so maybe that's the reason.  Or maybe we say that, as with *mitzvot*, we do not know which are more important and so any ongoing transgression would send somebody home, ideally so he can correct the problem, and these are just examples.

Comment: Rabbi Yose haglili says that averot derabanan also did exempt, Rabbi Yose, an other tana rules that averot mideorayta only can exempt him

Answer (score 2):

The sins are not enumerated, not by RYHG and not by RY. The purpose of RY is to give a paradigm of a Tora law, that is continuously violated.

Gemara Sota 44b:

> The Gemara asks: With regard to their understanding that the “fearful and fainthearted” is referring to one harboring sins, what difference is there between the opinion of Rabbi Yosei and the opinion of **Rabbi Yosei HaGelili**? The Gemara answers: There is a practical difference between them with regard to a sin which violates a prohibition by **rabbinic law**. According to Rabbi Yosei HaGelili, one who has violated a rabbinic law **returns home**, whereas Rabbi **Yosei maintains** that one returns home **only** if he has violated a **Torah law**, as in the case of a priest who has married a divorcée. The Gemara asks: In accordance with whose opinion is that which is taught in a baraita: **If one spoke between donning the phylactery of the arm and the phylactery of the head, he has a sin on his hands, and due to that sin he returns from the ranks of soldiers waging war**. In accordance with whose opinion does this man return? It is in accordance with the opinion of **Rabbi Yosei HaGelili**, who maintains that one returns even due to a minor transgression.